# Why my code using AES 256 in CBC works even without padding?

Tags: python, c, dll, aes, cbc-mode

I'm using Python3 to call a DLL which contains [this](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) implementation of AES encryption. I'm using it in AES-256 CBC mode.
Even though I'm not applying any padding scheme when I have to encrypt data with byte length not multiple of 16, **it still works when I decrypt it**, returning the fully unencrypted and functional file, be it an exe, jpg or rar. 
So the question is: how can it be?

Here is the piece of Python code that calls 'aes.dll' library. Note that I embed byte representation of the dll in embdll, in order to create the needed dll from code and subsequently call functions from it.

```
from ctypes import *
import os


class AES_ctx(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
    ('RoundKey', c_ubyte * 240),
    ('Iv', c_ubyte * 16)
               ]

embdll = (very long bytestring that represents compiled dll for easy deploying)
dllport = open("aes.dll","wb+")
dllport.write(embdll)
dllport.close()

mydll = CDLL("aes.dll")

mydll.AES_init_ctx_iv.argtypes = [
                                 POINTER(AES_ctx), POINTER(c_ubyte * 32), POINTER(c_ubyte * 16)
                                 ]

mydll.AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer.argtypes = [
                                        POINTER(AES_ctx), POINTER(c_ubyte), c_int
                                        ]

mydll.AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer.argtypes = [
                                        POINTER(AES_ctx), POINTER(c_ubyte), c_int
                                        ]

key = (os.urandom(32))
iv = (os.urandom(16))
file = open("MouseXY.exe","rb")
data = file.read()

file.close()
ctx_enc = AES_ctx()
ctx_dec = AES_ctx()
mydll.AES_init_ctx_iv(byref(ctx_enc), cast(key, POINTER(c_ubyte * 32)), cast(iv, POINTER(c_ubyte * 16)));
mydll.AES_init_ctx_iv(byref(ctx_dec), cast(key, POINTER(c_ubyte * 32)), cast(iv, POINTER(c_ubyte * 16)));


print("Raw data is "+str(len(data))+" bytes long.\n")


mydll.AES_CBC_encrypt_buffer(byref(ctx_enc), cast(data, POINTER(c_ubyte)), len(data))
file = open("MouseXY_enc.exe","wb+")
file.write(data)
file.close()
mydll.AES_CBC_decrypt_buffer(byref(ctx_dec), cast(data, POINTER(c_ubyte)), len(data))
file = open("MouseXY_dec.exe","wb+")
file.write(data)
file.close()
os.remove("aes.dll")
input("Done. Press any key to continue...")
```

Comment: Does the file sizes are same after decryption? Are you sure that they are not multiple of 16 bytes?

Comment: Yes, files i passed to the script for encryption are not multiples of 16 bytes and sizes remain the same whether the file is encrypted or decrypted...

Comment: That is interesting. I looked at the code and did not see a padding and un-padding mechanism. Either there is a mechanism between you and the core library that handles the padding, or you are doing it :)

Comment: I assure you no padding mechanism is implemented, not in my code or in aes.c code (as the author explicitly says in GitHub repo). I'm suspecting that since encryption/decryption implementation of buffer in 256 bit CBC mode loops over the uint8_t array of data 32 bytes per iteration, when it reaches the end it accesses out of boundary elements and uses them in AES algorithm to compensate the lack of bytes needed to make it a multiple of 16, but it should show undefined behaviour if this was correct AND file size should still be multiple of 16.

Comment: Could you check it before writing the file, and possibly by encryption small information like 1.